# Intellisense wont show members in class

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, javascript-intellisense

Hello I have a really annoying problem.
Usually IntelliSense should show the members of a class i made for example:

[image: Member list outside a class]

However this only seems to work outside of classes.
if i try the same thing inside a Class it only shows members that i already
used in this class:

[image: Member list outside a class]

I've already tried this

```
this.rectangle = /**@type {Rectangle} */(new Rectangle());
```

but it still does not work.